# Microcontroller to process HDMI frames

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, hdmi

I am looking for a microcontroller to process 1 HDMI input, manipulate the frame, and output to 1 HDMI output. What can I use?

Comment: I think you'll find that microcontrollers are not well suited to your application. HDMI is a ton of data, and much of it is encrypted (your device will appear as an unauthenticated device in the chain and degrade the stream). You're also not specific on how you want to "manipulate" the stream, which will affect the advice people give you. If you want something more manageable, check out sparkfun's [MAX7456 breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9168) which allows you to put a monochrome text overlay on an analog stream.

Comment: I don't think a microcontroller can do the job; this is the task for a DSP or for a more powerful microprocessor.

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple MCU solution to do this, but for reference, [Texas Instruments DaVinci Digital Signal Processors (DSP)](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/dsp/video_processors/overview.page) would be a product line that is suited for this.

Take a look at the [TMS320DM8168](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320dm8168), then under the Related End Equipment you can get an idea of what you would need.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=2117 for a HDMI overlay device, but that's implemented on an FPGA.